# how do i acces instance loaded into frame in wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2017

I am creating a program, that needs 1-6 stopwatches. I created canvas, so I can dynamically position them, depending on how many will be there(depending on config). It renders everything in place as it is supposed.

```
Canvas myCanvas = new Canvas();
List<Frame> allframes = new List<Frame>();
int a = 0;

while (a < 3)
{ 
    Frame myframe = new Frame();
    myframe.Source = new Uri("stopwatch.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
    myframe.Width = 350;
    myframe.Height = 700;
    allframes.Add(myframe);

    Canvas.SetTop(myframe, 200);
    Canvas.SetLeft(myframe, (a * 370) + 20);
    myCanvas.Children.Add(myframe);

    a++;
}
this.Content = myCanvas; // this = MainWindow
```

I have a problem accessing instances of stopwatch. I cannot access their methods and parameters. I added each frame into List, so I can access it, but cannot target the stopwatch loaded into it.

I can get all the data from my frame, except the instance of that stopwatch that is loaded in it.

```
foreach (var item in allframes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
}
```

Picture tells more than 1000 words, they say ....

[image: stopwatches loaded and measuring time.]

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `Content` property of `item`

```
var stopWatch = item.Content as YourStopWatchType;
```

and then just use your `stopWatch.somePropertyYouWantToAccess`

A better approach would be to create 3 instances of `YourStopWatchType` and add them to `myCanvas.Children`.